# Oracle SQL query output by Transposing Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have oracle database table 'App' with few sample rows as following-

```
ID  NAME    SN
123 TV      032361097
123 CB      G92970256
236 TV      050791069
345 CB      45681089
456 TV  
456 CB
```

I want to get output in following format by Transposing Rows into Columns -

```
ID  NAME_TV SR_TV       NAME_CB SR_CB
123 TV      032361097   CB      G92970256
236 TV      050791069       
345                     CB      45681089
456 TV                  CB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with following query if there are only two valid values for name.

```
WITH
  tv as (select id, name, sn from app where name = 'TV'),
  cb as (select id, name, sn from app where name = 'CB')
SELECT 
  nvl(tv.id, cb.id) AS id,
  tv.name           AS name_tv,
  tv.sn             AS sn_tv,
  cb.name           AS name_cb,
  cb.sn             AS sn_cb
FROM tv
  FULL OUTER JOIN cb
    ON tv.id = cb.id;
```

For more values use more tricky PIVOT:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, name, sn
  FROM app
) PIVOT (
  MAX(name) as name, MAX(sn) as sn
  FOR name IN ('TV' as TV, 'CB' as CB) --put other name values there
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, 'TV' as name_tv, sum(case when name = 'TV' then sn end) as sn_tv,
        'CB' as name_cb, sum(case when name = 'CB' then sn end) as sn_cb
from app
group by id;
```

I do have a question:  Why do you have the `name_tv` and `name_cb` columns?  They seem redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the table on itself.

```
select tv.id,
        tv.name as name_tv, 
        tv.sn as sr_tv, 
        cb.name as name_cb,
        cb.sn as sr_cb   
from app tv
join app cb
on tv.id = cb.id
where tv.name = 'TV'
and cb.name = 'CB'
```